# IF(ISBLANK formula calculates 8.8 even though logical_test cell is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel

My formula `=IF(ISBLANK(C24),"",C2-C24)` still returns a value even though the C24 cell is blank.

C24 has the following formula: `=COUNTIFS('Paste Data Here'!A:A,'Wrkr-Csld List'!B18,'Paste Data Here'!D:D,"CF",'Paste Data Here'!F:F,"3/31")`

Must C24 be absolutely blank with no formula in order for it to work?

Comment: If there is a formula in the cell it is NOT blank.  Instead use `=IF(C24<>"",...` Also how can a countifs return a blank?  It would return 0.  I would guess you have a format to blank out `0`s.  so you may need: `=IF(C24<>0,...`

Comment: Thank you so much! Novice here. Yes, you're correct. I have formatted the cells with 0;;; to remove the 0. Which makes perfect sense to me now that you've pointed out the obvious, "...how can a countifs return a blank?". This solved my issue. You've made my day saving me tons of time. I already spent the better part of a day trying to solve it.

Comment: The thing to note is if there are spaces in a cell it will come up with won't be considered blank.  You can check the cell with the LEN formula to see if there is something there you don't notice.. In The answer below (Can't past images to comments) I put 2 spaces in A1, the in A2 (formula B2) used LEN and tried IF(ISBLANK in C1

Answer (score 0):

The thing to note is if there are spaces in a cell it will come up with won't be considered blank. You can check the cell with the LEN formula to see if there is something there you don't notice.. In The answer below (Can't past images to comments) I put 2 spaces in A1, the in A2 (formula B2) used LEN and tried IF(ISBLANK in C1

[image]

Comment: You can have a `=LEN(A1)` equal to `0` and still have `=ISBLANK(A1)` return `FALSE`.  Put `=""` in A1 and this will happen.

Comment: Thank you both!